# How to postpone img src url calculation in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have directive with the following template:

```
<img src="https://some.base.url&user={{user.img}}"/>
```

And don't want to send request to this url before {{user.img}} is replace with a real value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ng-src instead of src:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc

Answer (score 1):

Your code should use this:

```
<img ng-src="https://some.base.url&user={{user.img}}"/>
```

The browser is wicked aggressive in caching the images and so on. Giving it a "ng-src" attribute allows Angular the time it needs to process the src and then it sets it for you.

on a side note, you should do the same thing with "href" on anchor tags. Use "ng-href" instead of the "href". It will allow Angular the time it needs to process the expressions. [SEE HERE](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHref)